# How to access OrientDB bin scripts installed in Docker

Tags: docker, orientdb, orientdb-2.1

I have installed **OrientDB** inside **Docker**.I want to run scripts inside the **bin** folder .But I am not able to find any way to access the directory of OrientDB like a normal explorer. Is there any way I can use the Docker installation like a local installation so that I can see and interact with all the folders of OrientDB installation.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access them inside docker container, you can do this:
start the container, then `docker exec -i -t CONTAINER_NAME bash` or `docker exec -i -t CONTAINER_NAME /bin/sh`. If bash/sh is installed in this particular image, you will get to the shell and can what you want there.

Another way, and I think it's what you want is to use docker volumes. You [map](https://docs.docker.com/v1.10/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume) your host path to a container path, so  it sees whatever changes you do outside.

map some folder on your host system to the location orientdb expects and it will create files there. 
mapping excerpt from docker-compose.yml for mysql:

```
alldbhost:
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    image: percona:5.5
    volumes:
      - ./etc/timezone:/etc/timezone
      - /dev/shm/mysql/:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./etc/mysql/:/etc/mysql
      - /home/user/temp/mysql_replication:/local/mysql/binlog
    environment:
      TERM: xterm
```

actually, orientdb [manual](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb-docker.wiki/Home.html) provides these instructions:
`docker run --name orientdb -d -v <config_path>:/opt/orientdb/config -v <databases_path>:/opt/orientdb/databases -v <backup_path>:/opt/orientdb/backup -p 2424 -p 2480 nesrait/orientdb-2.0`

`-v <databases_path>:/opt/orientdb/databases` is a path on your host system where database files will be located

If you *installed* orientdb *inside* some container (ubuntu, for example) you should find orientdb config files, find where it stores databases and, again, map your host directory to container's

Comment: `docker run -d  -p 2424:2424 -p 2480:2480   \
        -v orientdb_config:/orientdb/config \
        -v orient_database:/orientdb/databases \
        -v orient_backup:/orientdb/backup  \
        -e ORIENTDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=$1   \
        --name orientdb \
        wikirating/orientdb:latest`  

This is the command I used but now can you tell me where all the files are resident?

Comment: `docker ps`, then `docker inspect containerName`, see where mounts are, go from there, check orientdb configs. `-v orient_database:/orientdb/databases` means you must create `orient_database` directory in your current working directory (or use an absoulte path - like `mkdir /home/user/odb/`  -  and then change your commandline `... -v /home/user/odb/:/orientdb/databases ...` )

Comment: Oh so you mean I need to create the respective folders for it on my disk so that the data can be saved there, I thought Docker creates then automatically!

Comment: maybe, maybe not. I almost never use raw docker, I prefer docker-compose to start a pack of linked containers

Comment: Thanks although I didn't actually understand the whole concept of this but still I was able to access the the filesystem thorough bash.

Comment: @AbhimanyuShekhawat buy or borrow this book  from a friend https://www.dockerbook.com